# How to map SceneKit sizes to artwork pixel sizes?

Tags: ios, 3d, sprite-kit, sprite, scenekit

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620742/use-xcode-scene-editor-to-center-and-resize-nodes-per-device) about creating static scenes in SceneKit, how are you supposed to map node sizes to artwork size?

Let's say you have a SCNSphere with a radius of 1. And inside the sphere you want to present a character sprite.

How do you decide how large the sprite artwork should be, that is, what is the relationship between the artwork pixel size and the SCNNode size?

For SpriteKit, this is done automatically as the nodes assume the size of the sprite textures by default.

Right now, the only solution seems to be a trial-and-error process where you try different sized artwork until one "fits" properly (i.e., not too small, not too big) inside the sphere, but surely there must be a more elegant approach?

Comment: I've also found the only way to be trial and error :(